# C# System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardOutput encoding

Tags: c#, powershell, encoding, cmd

How to pass process output (as for example power shell output), into my C# applications correctly?

Encoding of my machine is set to `CP437`.
I also work with more exotic encodings as `CP1250`.

*I know that on this site is a lot of similar questions - however, none of them was helpful for me.*

Let us say that I have a powershell script (Unicode) with such that output, e.g.:

```
echo "Příliš žluťoučký kůň měl ďábelský úsměv."
```

When I try to use powershell, everything works ok.

[image: powershell]

Even in cmd:

[image: cmd]

I need to get it in WPF application, thus I need to store that output as string:

```
        var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
        {
            StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "powershell",
                Arguments = "./MyScript.ps1",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                StandardOutputEncoding = myEncoding,
            },
        };
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

The `result` contains different values, depending on `myEncoding` value.

But none of them is what I expected. I thought that I had incorrect codepage, so I tried to profile them:

```
foreach (System.Text.EncodingInfo encoding in System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings())
{
    myEncoding = encoding.GetEncoding();
    ...
}
```

This is the result (line with problematic chars were deleted because of stackoverflow policy) - there is no correct output:

```
    CP37 - IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada):
    CP437 - OEM United States:
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP500 - IBM EBCDIC (International):
    CP708 - Arabic (ASMO 708):
         Pr┴lis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ├smev.
    CP720 - Arabic (DOS):
         Prةlis zlutoucky kun mel dبbelsky ثsmev.
    CP737 - Greek (DOS):
         Prκlis zlutoucky kun mel dιbelsky μsmev.
    CP775 - Baltic (DOS):
         PrĪlis zlutoucky kun mel dĀbelsky Żsmev.
    CP850 - Western European (DOS):
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP852 - Central European (DOS):
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP855 - OEM Cyrillic:
         PrАlis zlutoucky kun mel dаbelsky Бsmev.
    CP857 - Turkish (DOS):
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP858 - OEM Multilingual Latin I:
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP860 - Portuguese (DOS):
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP861 - Icelandic (DOS):
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP862 - Hebrew (DOS):
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP863 - French Canadian (DOS):
         Pr´lis zlutoucky kun mel d¦belsky úsmev.
    CP864 - Arabic (864):
         Pr­lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP865 - Nordic (DOS):
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP866 - Cyrillic (DOS):
         Prбlis zlutoucky kun mel dаbelsky гsmev.
    CP869 - Greek, Modern (DOS):
         Prΐlis zlutoucky kun mel dϊbelsky ύsmev.
    CP870 - IBM EBCDIC (Multilingual Latin-2):
    CP874 - Thai (Windows):
         Prกlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky ฃsmev.
    CP875 - IBM EBCDIC (Greek Modern):
    CP932 - Japanese (Shift-JIS):
         Pr｡lis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ｣smev.
    CP936 - Chinese Simplified (GB2312):
         Pris zlutoucky kun mel d燽elsky mev.
    CP949 - Korean:
         Pr죐is zlutoucky kun mel d쟟elsky 즧mev.
    CP950 - Chinese Traditional (Big5):
         Pr︼is zlutoucky kun mel delsky ωmev.
    CP1026 - IBM EBCDIC (Turkish Latin-5):
    CP1047 - IBM Latin-1:
    CP1140 - IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada-Euro):
    CP1141 - IBM EBCDIC (Germany-Euro):
    CP1142 - IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway-Euro):
    CP1143 - IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden-Euro):
    CP1144 - IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro):
    CP1145 - IBM EBCDIC (Spain-Euro):
    CP1146 - IBM EBCDIC (UK-Euro):
    CP1147 - IBM EBCDIC (France-Euro):
    CP1148 - IBM EBCDIC (International-Euro):
    CP1149 - IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic-Euro):
    CP1200 - Unicode:
    CP1201 - Unicode (Big-Endian):
    CP1250 - Central European (Windows):
         Prˇlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky Łsmev.
    CP1251 - Cyrillic (Windows):
         PrЎlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky Јsmev.
    CP1252 - Western European (Windows):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP1253 - Greek (Windows):
         Pr΅lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP1254 - Turkish (Windows):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP1255 - Hebrew (Windows):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP1256 - Arabic (Windows):
         Pr،lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP1257 - Baltic (Windows):
         Prlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP1258 - Vietnamese (Windows):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP1361 - Korean (Johab):
         Pr멻is zlutoucky kun mel d막elsky 믑mev.
    CP10000 - Western European (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky £smev.
    CP10001 - Japanese (Mac):
         Pr｡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky ｣smev.
    CP10002 - Chinese Traditional (Mac):
         Pr︼is zlutoucky kun mel delsky ωmev.
    CP10003 - Korean (Mac):
         Pr?is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ?mev.
    CP10004 - Arabic (Mac):
         Prlis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky smev.
    CP10005 - Hebrew (Mac):
         Prlis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky smev.
    CP10006 - Greek (Mac):
         PrΓlis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky Θsmev.
    CP10007 - Cyrillic (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky £smev.
    CP10008 - Chinese Simplified (Mac):
         Pr?is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ?mev.
    CP10010 - Romanian (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky £smev.
    CP10017 - Ukrainian (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky £smev.
    CP10021 - Thai (Mac):
         Prกlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky ฃsmev.
    CP10029 - Central European (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky £smev.
    CP10079 - Icelandic (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel dÝbelsky £smev.
    CP10081 - Turkish (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky £smev.
    CP10082 - Croatian (Mac):
         Pr°lis zlutoucky kun mel d†belsky £smev.
    CP12000 - Unicode (UTF-32):
         ����������
    CP12001 - Unicode (UTF-32 Big-Endian):
         ����������
    CP20000 - Chinese Traditional (CNS):
         Pr伬is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky 弝mev.
    CP20001 - TCA Taiwan:
         Pr脾is zlutoucky kun mel d插elsky 碓mev.
    CP20002 - Chinese Traditional (Eten):
         Pr脾is zlutoucky kun mel d插elsky 碓mev.
    CP20003 - IBM5550 Taiwan:
         Pr膝is zlutoucky kun mel d墮elsky 輳mev.
    CP20004 - TeleText Taiwan:
         Pr佢is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ?mev.
    CP20005 - Wang Taiwan:
         Pr暉is zlutoucky kun mel d跋elsky 嗾mev.
    CP20105 - Western European (IA5):
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP20106 - German (IA5):
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP20107 - Swedish (IA5):
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP20108 - Norwegian (IA5):
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP20127 - US-ASCII:
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP20261 - T.61:
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky £smev.
    CP20269 - ISO-6937:
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP20273 - IBM EBCDIC (Germany):
    CP20277 - IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway):
    CP20278 - IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden):
    CP20280 - IBM EBCDIC (Italy):
    CP20284 - IBM EBCDIC (Spain):
    CP20285 - IBM EBCDIC (UK):
    CP20290 - IBM EBCDIC (Japanese katakana):
    CP20297 - IBM EBCDIC (France):
    CP20420 - IBM EBCDIC (Arabic):
    CP20423 - IBM EBCDIC (Greek):
    CP20424 - IBM EBCDIC (Hebrew):
    CP20833 - IBM EBCDIC (Korean Extended):
    CP20838 - IBM EBCDIC (Thai):
    CP20866 - Cyrillic (KOI8-R):
         Pr║lis zlutoucky kun mel d═belsky ёsmev.
    CP20871 - IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic):
    CP20880 - IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Russian):
    CP20905 - IBM EBCDIC (Turkish):
    CP20924 - IBM Latin-1:
    CP20932 - Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990):
         Pr・is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ・mev.
    CP20936 - Chinese Simplified (GB2312-80):
         Pr?is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ?mev.
    CP20949 - Korean Wansung:
         Pr?is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ?mev.
    CP21025 - IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Serbian-Bulgarian):
    CP21866 - Cyrillic (KOI8-U):
         Pr║lis zlutoucky kun mel d═belsky ёsmev.
    CP28591 - Western European (ISO):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP28592 - Central European (ISO):
         PrĄlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky Łsmev.
    CP28593 - Latin 3 (ISO):
         PrĦlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP28594 - Baltic (ISO):
         PrĄlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky Ŗsmev.
    CP28595 - Cyrillic (ISO):
         PrЁlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky Ѓsmev.
    CP28596 - Arabic (ISO):
         Prlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky smev.
    CP28597 - Greek (ISO):
         Prʽlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP28598 - Hebrew (ISO-Visual):
         Prlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP28599 - Turkish (ISO):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP28603 - Estonian (ISO):
         Pr”lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP28605 - Latin 9 (ISO):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP29001 - Europa:
         Prílis zlutoucky kun mel dábelsky úsmev.
    CP38598 - Hebrew (ISO-Logical):
         Prlis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP50220 - Japanese (JIS):
         Pr｡lis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ｣smev.
    CP50221 - Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana):
         Pr｡lis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ｣smev.
    CP50222 - Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI):
         Pr｡lis zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ｣smev.
    CP50225 - Korean (ISO):
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP50227 - Chinese Simplified (ISO-2022):
         Pris zlutoucky kun mel d燽elsky mev.
    CP51932 - Japanese (EUC):
         Pr・is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ・mev.
    CP51936 - Chinese Simplified (EUC):
         Pris zlutoucky kun mel d燽elsky mev.
    CP51949 - Korean (EUC):
         Pr?is zlutoucky kun mel dbelsky ?mev.
    CP52936 - Chinese Simplified (HZ):
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP54936 - Chinese Simplified (GB18030):
         Pris zlutoucky kun mel d燽elsky mev.
    CP57002 - ISCII Devanagari:
         Prँlis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ःsmev.
    CP57003 - ISCII Bengali:
         Prঁlis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ঃsmev.
    CP57004 - ISCII Tamil:
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ஃsmev.
    CP57005 - ISCII Telugu:
         Prఁlis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ఃsmev.
    CP57006 - ISCII Assamese:
         Prঁlis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ঃsmev.
    CP57007 - ISCII Oriya:
         Prଁlis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ଃsmev.
    CP57008 - ISCII Kannada:
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ಃsmev.
    CP57009 - ISCII Malayalam:
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ഃsmev.
    CP57010 - ISCII Gujarati:
         Prઁlis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ઃsmev.
    CP57011 - ISCII Punjabi:
         Pr?lis zlutoucky kun mel d?belsky ?smev.
    CP65000 - Unicode (UTF-7):
         Pr¡lis zlutoucky kun mel d belsky £smev.
    CP65001 - Unicode (UTF-8):
         Pr�lis zlutoucky kun mel d�belsky �smev.
```

Is there anything I missed to be able to get my original string?

Comment: If you're doing the saving, why not just store everything as UTF8?

Comment: `Arguments = "[Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false; ./MyScript.ps1"`, `StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: @PetSerAl nice, but not universal - I would like to pass any program, not just `powershell`. Let us thing about `powercfg -list` without exploiting power shell.  Anyway thank you.

Comment: @user4663214 I doubt, that there is universal solution. You could probably make it work with `cmd /c "chcp 65001 & program.exe"` in most cases, but some programs simply do not respect console output page and do whatever they want.

Comment: All it looks like double mojibake. Add `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` line to your `MyScript.ps1` script  and share the result.